# How to move a window to a different workspace using its ID, in bash?

Tags: shell, workspaces, wmctrl

Currently I have successfully used  `wmctrl  -r :SELECT: -t 2`  but something like  `wmctrl -r -i 0x03e00003 -t 2` does not work. How should I write the command in order to select the window to be moved by ID not by mouse?

I am using Linux Mint 13 with the default MATE DE .

I have also tried `wmctrl  -i -r 0x03e00003 -t 2`

EDIT1:  `wmctrl  -i -r thewinIDInHexa -t 2` works now. The reason why it did not work is that while the first time i experimented with wmctrl i used the right ID but wrong syntax, the 2nd time i used the correct form but the wrong window ID... the thing is the ID was non-existent and wmctrl does not output any message for non-existent IDs.  Thank you for your efforts. Having confirmation that i was in fact using the right form for the command pushed me to double check the IDs. Thank you again

EDIT2: since i am unable to comment i will post here the response to @slm  :
the correct ID now is  0x0380000f

```
wmctrl -v -i -r 0x0380000f -t 2



envir_utf8: 1
Using window: 0x0380000f
```

VLC is moved to workspace #2 (3rd workspace)

for the ID  that is actually non-existent we have  pretty much the same thing:

```
wmctrl -v -i -r 0x03a00003 -t 2 

envir_utf8: 1
Using window: 0x03a00003
```

Comment: It needs to be `wmctrl  -i -r 0x03e00003`, the option `-r` must be followed by the window ID. That command works for me (in a different window manager).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you're getting confused with the `-t #` switch. The windows are numbered as starting with a 1 but the first window is actually number 0. Notice in the output of `wmctrl -l`:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x00c00028 -1 grinchy Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x0120001e  0 grinchy x-nautilus-desktop
0x06015fee  0 grinchy saml@grinchy:~
0x06000004  0 grinchy saml@grinchy:~
0x05a000d1  0 grinchy xorg - How can I get information about my virtual desktops via the command line? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange - Google Chrome
```

The 2nd column is the number of the desktop. So when you're using `-t 2` it's actually putting the window `-r 0x03e00003` on the 3rd desktop, not the 2nd.

#### Example

Evince PDF window starts on desktop #1 (0):

```
$ wmctrl -l | grep 0x03a00003
0x03a00003  0 greeneggs.bubba.net Packt.Puppet.3.Beginners.Guide.pdf
```

Move it to desktop #3 (2):

```
$ wmctrl -i -r 0x03a00003 -t 2
```

Confirm:

```
$ wmctrl -l | grep 0x03a00003
0x03a00003  2 greeneggs.bubba.net Packt.Puppet.3.Beginners.Guide.pdf
```

Notice which window it's on though:

[image: ss #1]

It's on desktop #3!

#### References

- [How can I get information about my virtual desktops via the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94193/how-can-i-get-information-about-my-virtual-desktops-via-the-command-line/94195#94195)

Comment: thank you for the info and the effort you put into your answer  but i knew the desktops start from 0. That was not the issue ( i would have noticed when using `wmctrl -r :SELECT: -t 2` ). The issue is `wmctrl -i -r 0x03a00003 -t 2` does not do anything for me....

Comment: @tardem - OK, thought that might be the issue. What does the verbose switch show when you run this command? `wmctrl -v -i -r 0x03a00003 -t 2`?